# jquery select children of an element based on a specific attribute that they have

Tags: jquery

How can I select childrens of an element based on the value of a specific attribute that each children possess ?

```
<div id="notifs">
    <a href="#" viewed="false">Notif 1</a>
    <a href="#" viewed="true">Notif 2</a>
    <a href="#" viewed="false">Notif 3</a>
</div>

$('#notif').children() - I would like to get all but the second notif.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/). There are a number of variations using different wilcards so it is worth reading through the docs just to know what can be done using them

```
$('#notif a[viewed="false"]')
// or using method like children, find etc
$('#notif').children('[viewed="false"]')
```